# I can't get the delete link button on gridview to work

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, gridview

[image: Latest error]
I am currently creating an asp.net web app in C# using Visual Studio. I have a gridview that displays data from a database table and I have added the datasource manually in my .cs page as I have converted the childrens DOB into age, thus enabling me to filter the gridview with a dropdown list of age groups. This all works fine, the only issue i'm having is getting the delete link button to work. I need it to completely delete the child from the database table if clicked.

I began by going to the gridview in design mode, Add new column --> Button field (button type 'link', command name 'delete') and then adding the following code in my .cs page:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {
        LinkButton lnkRemove = (LinkButton)sender;

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "delete from  children where " +
        "childID=@childID";           
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@childID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value
            = lnkRemove.CommandArgument;
        GridView1.DataSource = source;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

When I run the page and click delete next to any of the children, I get the following error:

[image: Error]

I will include the full code from my .cs page as well as my source code. Can someone help me figure out why I am getting the error and why the delete buttons wont delete without issue? Thanks in advance.

FULL .CS CODE:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;


namespace Coursework
{
public partial class Testy1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    //create a datasource
    SqlDataSource source = new SqlDataSource();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //always set some defaults for the sqldatasource
        source.ID = "source1";
        source.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["newregDBConnectionString"].ConnectionStr‌​ing;
        source.SelectCommand = "SELECT firstname, dob, DATEDIFF(hour, dob, GETDATE()) / 8766 AS age FROM children ORDER BY age";

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            //bind the grid
            GridView1.DataSource = source;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }       
    protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //the new database query, now with where clause
        source.SelectCommand = "SELECT firstname, dob, DATEDIFF(hour, dob, GETDATE()) / 8766 AS age FROM children WHERE (DATEDIFF(hour, dob, GETDATE()) / 8766 BETWEEN @start AND @end) ORDER BY age";

        //get the end age from the dropdown and cast as int
        int end = Convert.ToInt32(DropDownList1.SelectedValue);

        //get the start int for the filter
        int start = end - 2;

        //if the filter is resetted, make sure the query returns all ages
        if (end == 5)
        {
            start = 5;
            end = 99;
        }

        //replace the parameters in the query
        source.SelectParameters.Add("start", start.ToString());
        source.SelectParameters.Add("end", end.ToString());

        //rebind the grid
        GridView1.DataSource = source;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }

    protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void GridView1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {
        LinkButton lnkRemove = (LinkButton)sender;

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "delete from  children where " +
        "childID=@childID";           
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@childID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value
            = lnkRemove.CommandArgument;
        GridView1.DataSource = source;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

SOURCE CODE:

```
 <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Testy1.aspx.cs" Inherits="Coursework.Testy1" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Filter age" Value="5"></asp:ListItem>  
    <asp:ListItem Text="5 - 7" Value="7"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="8 - 10" Value="10"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="11 - 13" Value="13"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="14 - 16" Value="16"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" OnRowDeleting="GridView1_RowDeleting" >
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# Eval("firstname") %>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="DOB">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("dob")).ToString("d MMMM yyyy") %>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Age">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# Eval("age") %>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:ButtonField CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: You have not even assigned a `CommandArgument` to the button-field.

Comment: In the source code or in the .cs page? I have only ever used the delete function when connecting automatically to a datasource with no .cs code so i'm new to this way of doing things!

Comment: here `LinkButton lnkRemove = (LinkButton)sender;` sender is GridView not linkbutton

Comment: Oh, so it is the wrong code for the link button that I added to my grid view? What should it be instead?

Comment: I should add that my professor told us that we would barely need to touch the source code for this project so we won't be taught much until the next term. So I am unfamiliar with it right now, as well as a beginner with C# and asp.net!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `sender` is the `GridView` in `RowDeleting`, not the button, so your cast fails.

If you would specify the `DataKeyNames` you could use  the GridView's [`DataKeys`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.datakeys(v=vs.110).aspx) property:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" 
             DataKeyNames = "childID"
             OnRowDeleting="GridView1_RowDeleting" >
```

Codebehind:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    string childId = GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
    string deleteSql = @"DELETE FROM Children 
                         WHERE childID = @childID;";
    using(var con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["newregDBConnectionString"].ConnectionStr‌​ing))
    using(var cmd = new SqlCommand(deleteSql, con))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@childID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = childId;
        con.Open();
        int deleted = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    GridView1.DataSource = GetDataSource();  // provide a method that returns it
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Thank you Tim, I am trying to implement your solution but am getting an error under 'GetDataSource' on line GridView1.DataSource = GetDataSource();  // provide a method that returns it. What method would I need to replace the 'GetDataSource' with? Thanks.

Comment: Ok, I realised that like above, the method that returns it is just 'source'

Comment: @ACostea: yes, i don't like using fields for this, i would encapsulate it in a method, but at the end it's source, yes

Comment: Ok, I think I am close but I am receiving a new error when pressing delete. Could you look at it? (i've included it as a screenshot at the top of my original question) Thanks again Tim.

Comment: @ACostea: you should really get familiar with the debugger. Set a breakpoint before this line and inspect the value of `childId` in the debugger.

Comment: The childID in my case is the username that the child registers with and it is my primary key in the database table. The childID's aren't just numbers if that helps with the error?

Comment: @ACostea: you should not use a username as primary key but a unique numeric value. However, in this case it's simple. I will edit my answer

Comment: That's what I thought as in my last year I used unique numerical values for my PKs but my coursework specification insists that the children PK are stored as their usernames.

Comment: I receive a new error when changing the code you just updated. An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Failed to convert parameter value from a DataKey to a String.

Comment: At line "int deleted = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();"

Comment: @ACostea: have you used my (modified) code? Look at the first line: `string childId = GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();`

Comment: I missed that piece of updated code. Thanks so much for your help Tim, I will make you the answer now. Have a great Christmas!

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are handling GridView's Deleting event, not button's click. So your sender is actually a GridView control, you should not cast it to LinkButton.

Besides, you did not assign CommandArgument. Should be something like that:

```
<asp:ButtonField CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("childID") %>' />
```

But even if you did, this is not going to help as CommandArgument is not passed along with Delete even args. Thus, you have two options.

First is to switch to handling RowCommand event:

```
OnRowDeleting="GridView1_RowCommand"
```

In there you need to check that command is actually a delete one, and use command arg to delete:

```
if (e.CommandName == "Delete")
{
    // parse e.CommandArgument and delete
}
```

Second is to define primary keys for the rows.

```
DataKeyNames="childID"
```

This is going to be available via event args of Deleting event:

```
e.Keys
```

You do not need to set CommandArgument at all in this case.